# Creating a dummy server for unit testing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, http, testing

I maintain a few Ruby gems that process remote files using `net/http`.

My current unit test setup involves starting up a WEBrick server in the `setup` method, then killing it in `teardown`.

```
def setup
  return if @server_thread
  @server_thread = Thread.new do
    s = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 12000, :DocumentRoot => www_root, :Logger => Log.new(nil, BasicLog::ERROR), :AccessLog => [])
    port = s.config[:Port]
    begin
      s.start
    ensure
      s.shutdown
    end
  end
end
```

With Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 I've been getting a bunch of connection errors - `Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)`. Even more frustrating is that they're transient -- sometimes they happen, sometimes not.  All I can think is that WEBrick is either being overwhelmed, or not setup properly in the first place.

I need to be able to load multiple static files (in my fixtures directory) over HTTP to test these gems.  What's the best practice for creating a dummy HTTP server to use in `Test::Unit` testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would mock the `net/http` class to return the static files content. Use **dependency injection** so that the class under test uses the mock during the unit test exection and `net/http` in production.

You can also use the [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) or [fakeweb](http://fakeweb.rubyforge.org/) gems.